# NSView Absorb Clicks?

Tags: objective-c, macos, click, nsview

I have my standard app setup, window with lots of views. From time to time I place an NSView over the top of everything, black with some transparency, to act an a dimmer/overlay.

I need this top overlay view to absorb all clicks so that any views underneath it can't be interacted with. E.g. an NSButton under this NSView won't be clickable.

How can I do this?

I have seen `-(NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint` but I don't want to put this on every single subview with a rule to block clicks while the overlay view is present.

Comment: If you have a view that covers the entire window I believe the views underneath should not receive any mouse events. Otherwise try override `mouseDown:` (with nothing in it).

Comment: Well that did the trick! I didn't realise that would work. I could click through the NSView until adding an empty `mouseDown` method as you mention. Thanks! Feel free to make it an official answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override the NSView with an empty `mouseDown:` and the views underneath will not receive any mouse events.